# How to track changes from a remote master repository and use git pull?

Tags: git, github

I forked a group repository to my own personal repository.

Instead of keeping my forked repository up to date using:

```
$ git co master
$ git fetch upstream
$ git rebase upstream/master
```

Is there a way I can set up my forked repository to track changes from the remote master repository and do something simple like this?

```
$ git co master
$ git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can set up my forked repository to track changes from the remote master repository and do something simple like this?

[Not on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/). If you have access to a VPS you could create a Cronjob that performs the first task for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a different push and pull origin if you want to:
First set URL of the original one

`$ git remote set-url origin url-to-the-original/global.git`

Then set the push origin to your forked one

`$ git remote set-url --push origin url-to-fork/forked.git`

Answer (score 0):

You can set for the checked out branch a remote tracking branch:

```
$ git branch -u <remote_name>/<remote_branch>
```

In most cases this will be:

```
$ git branch -u origin/master
```

Every subsequent `git pull` will automatically use this remote branch.

For rebasing you can use the `-r` flag of pull

```
$ git pull -r
```